# segfault using scipy griddata: ceval_gil.h no found

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have been searching for an answer for a while now, but cannot seem to find it. I am running an interpolation routine for scattered data to receive an interpolation on a grid. The relevant code segments are found below:

```
# some code to load and format data
##### build meshgrid using scipy griddata
# see example at : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html
# within numeric accuracy the second dimension is always the same value,
# i.e. the model results are on a plane circle in the x-y plane
# minimum pt spacing is <0.17 -> 10000 points per dim gives spacing of ~ 0.28
grid_x, grid_y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(np.min(pts[:,0]), np.max(pts[:,0]), 1e4),
                             np.linspace(np.min(pts[:,1]), np.max(pts[:,1]), 1e4))

grid_z = np.ones(grid_x.shape)*pts[0,2] # mean is way overkill as they are all the same within 1e-15

# interpolate each component using cubic spline interpolation
for f in range(E.shape[2]) :
    grid_Ex = griddata(pts[:,:2], E[:,0,f], (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
    grid_Ey = griddata(pts[:,:2], E[:,1,f], (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
    grid_Ez = griddata(pts[:,:2], E[:,2,f], (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
    # further code
```

The problem I have is that when I run the code I get a segfault at the first griddata line. 
pts is a (n,3) numpy array of type float (irregularily points) and E a (n,3,8) numpy array of complex type.

Using

```
gdb python3
myscript.py
```

I receive the output

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
take_gil (tstate=0x3ff0000000000000) at Python/ceval_gil.h:254
254     Python/ceval_gil.h: No such file or directory.
```

I cannot locate the relevant file ceval_gil.h on the system so I was hoping you could give me a clue as to what the problem is as I could not find it mentioned anywhere using the g00gles.

I am running Python 3.4.1 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| built using GCC 4.4.7 on a Ubuntu 12.04 
griddata is imported using "from scipy.interpolate import griddata" without errors

Thanks in advance for any help and apologies if I did not search thoroughly enough.

PS: Writing this I just had the idea, whether it could have to do with Anaconda not being the standard python3 on Ubuntu 12.04 (which is python3.2 I think)???

EDIT1:

## So I have ruled out a couple of problems:

1. It has nothing to do with stack size: I increased the stacksize via $ulimit -s 16000 and also split up the calculation to require only a 10th of the memory (well below what we have available, yet the problem persists.
2. It has nothing to do with how the grid is generated or the particular way of how to use the formatting of griddata. The same result appears, regardless of how the data is supplied (2D arrays or 1D vectors).
3. I have ruled out the PS above, i.e. that anaconda is not the default ubuntu 12.04 python3 by installing all necessary python3.2 packages on the machine and running it with the native python. Same result.
4. I have ruled out, that it's the supplied data type. E in the code segment above is of dtype complex. Casting E.astype(float) does not solve the problem. (pts is already dtype float)
5. I have ruled out, that some of the supplied data is NaN by removing that data altogether. The NaN would result in a funny 'NaN+0j' complex number, which is rather odd. Either way, this did not sort things out either.

Going forward I will now check whether I can achieve my results using interp2D. Should I file this as a bug in the SciPy forums, or is there a chance that this might get answered?

EDIT2:

Although in principle interp2D as well as SmoothBivariateSpline can do the same job they handle large data sets well. As this is with 14.000+ pts interpolated on a 10.000² grid and this 96 times (8 frequencies times 3 axes times 2 fitting variables, real and imaginary separately as FITPACK cannot handle complex numbers) the interpolation throws a tantrum of warnings of having too much data for fitting, takes forever and the errors are unacceptable (probably due to the previous warnings). I now had to revert to an old IDL code from a colleague, which I had to adapt and run the interpolation IDL, then port the whole thing to python and save the interpolated data as npz, so I can access it again later on. Luckily I will only have to do this once, as that is enough. It is sad though that I have to say that in this case IDL performes incredibly well compared to python(which I would generally not be willing to admit).

It would be great if someone found a solution to this at some point, but I will not put further effort into it for now.